# Concatenating numbers in vim

Tags: vim

i have a series of hexadecimal numbers as shown below in colums.

```
cdef
89ab
4567
0123
```

I would want to arrange the numbers in one single row starting from the last row as follows.

i.e **0123456789abcdef**. How can i get it done in vim without using macros?

Answer (score 4):

**The commands**

Reverse the lines with

```
:g/./m 0
```

Join all the lines and the `!` flag does not insert or remove white-space.

```
:%j!
```

**The Explanation**

The `:global` command takes the form: `:g/{pat}/{cmd}`. So run command `{cmd}` on ever line that matches pattern `{pat}`. In this case our pattern is `.` which matches a non empty line. Our command is `:move`. The `:move {address}` command will move a whole line to an address/line, `{address}`. In our case we are moving each line to the top of the file so we use `0`.

All together the `:g/./m0` will take every non empty line and move it to the top. Since the `:global` command runs from the top of the file to the bottom, the first line gets moved to the top first and the last line get moved to the top of the file last. Think of this kind of like a stack (LILO). Therefore the lines are reversed.

Now all that is left is the join all the lines together with out any extra white space. The `:join` command takes the form `:{range}join[!]`. We want to join from the first line, `1`, to the last line, `$`, so our range would be `1,$`. However this is very common so there is a shortcut for this range, `%`. The optional `!` flag tells `:join` to not add or remove any white space. All together `:%j!` will concatenate the lines into one long line.

As a side note is probably more common to reverse the lines via `:g/^/m0` as the `^` pattern matches every line not just non-empty lines.

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :m
:h :j
```

Comment: Could u please explain whta ./m 0 does?

Answer (score 1):

with Join plugin (https://github.com/sk1418/Join) you could just do:

```
:%J '' r
```

or

```
:J '' 4 r
```

`r` flag means join lines in reverse

to achieve the goal.  It supports more features regarding line joining. check it out..

and.... that script was written by me. :P

Comment: without using any scripts how can i do it.

Comment: @powernest check the other nice answers.

Answer (score 1):

Kent's plugin does the job and is recommended if you need to do this often; here's a (more long-winded) alternative with built-in commands:

First, use the `:move` command together with `:global` to reverse the lines.

```
:1,4g/^/m0
```

Then, join without any separator:

```
:1,4j!
```

Comment: +1, the command (g/^/m0) lets me recall the time when I just began to use vim. It took some times for me to understand how vim does the  `tac` magic!